# Am I using Jquery's .on() Correctly here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm currently trying to do something a little fancy with a WordPress Plugin Contact Form 7. This plugin kindly provides several types of custom DOM events that can be used within your code to run a function in a specific situation.

Specifically, I'm targeting the `wpcf7mailsent` event. Used initially like so;

```
// on submit move to last panel
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    clicked = 'true';
    console.log("wpcf7mailsent: Fire");
    panelNavigator();
}, false );
```

I'm using Jquery primarily though so I wanted to convert this event listener into JQ. I've read that `.bind()` is now depreciated and I should more so opt to use `.on()`. So here's my crack at it;

```
// on submit move to last panel 
$('.ms-pricing-form').on( 'wpcf7mailsent', function() {
    clicked = 'true'; // just a bool for later use in panelNavigator();
    console.log("wpcf7mailsent: Fire");
    panelNavigator(); // calling panelNavigator();
});
```

**This currently works fine.**

---

**My Question: Am I using `.on()`. correctly here?**

In the pure JS version, you don't have to specify the submitting form? but with `.on()` I've had to specify the form by using `.ms-pricing-form`. Don't get me wrong it's great that it works but I just want to make sure I'm not making any rookie errors or dumb mistakes.

Comment: Looks fine.....

Comment: Awesome, I'm happy as long as I'm not doing anything silly. 

Comment: so using `$(document).on( 'wpcf7mailsent'` would be the same as you js code so that's correct